# How to destroy derived from QWindow object immediately after constructor done?

Tags: c++, qt, destroy, qt-events, qwindow

I need to destroy derived from `QWindow` object immediately after constructor done if some conditions in constructor will be true.

There is member variable which I want to set in constructor and check in window initializing function. But I don't know which function or signal is suitable for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [QObject::deleteLater()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) to safely delete your object. Just
 call it in your constructor when the condition is true :

```
if(condition)
{
   this->deleteLater();
   return;
}
```